# Sql Server 2016 "The Parameter Is Incorrect" Foreign Key on Database Diagram

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm running in to a few strange issues when using database diagrams in Sql Server 2016...

First, I cannot create relationships by dragging and dropping between columns, both in the same and in different tables.

Secondly, when I try to create a foreign key relationship manually in the Database Diagram, or open the database diagram with a table containing a foreign key relationship with another table in the diagram, I receiver a "The Parameter Is Incorrect" error, and it gets stuck trying to load the diagram, while repeatedly generating the error over and over.

I know I've done this before, and I know it's supposed to work... If anyone can alleviate me of my problem, it would be greatly appreciated!

FYI:

Windows 10 Pro

SQL Server 2016

Server hosted on Microsoft Azure

Thanks!

Comment: I also have this problem and have not found a solution. This issue is also happening on a local install, not just Azure. The most current SSMS still has the issue.

Comment: I have this too. I migrated diagrams using BCP from Sql 2012 to Sql 2016 and not all the relationships show, worse when I try to drag a column to add a relationship nothing happens (I dont even get The Parameter is incorrect). I will have to roll back to Sql 2012, but our server is 2016! Nightmare

Comment: @Brian What's your Manager Studio Version ? . 
I am try use  Database Diagram It's worked 
DB Ver : SQL Server 2016 developer 
Manager Studio : 13.0.16106.4

Comment: Is there a way you could add some screenshots to the question? It's the icon after {} when you edit..

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete shot in the dark but i used to face a similar issue for mySQL - more to do with foreign key relationships. Its possible you may need to drop foreign key constraints in some way whilst you enter the relationship in manually. And then return back to normal. I dont know if there is any setting like this for SQL server 16 but thought it might be something to look at